# ошибка при захвате изображения с ip камеры ``` [rtsp @ 0xf3200fa0] RTP: PT=69: bad cseq 77f7 expected=6736 ```

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, cv2, gstreamer

У меня есть ip камера, с которой я пытаюсь получить изображение.
Я использую данный код:

```
import cv2
import queue
import time
import threading
q=queue.Queue()

def Receive():
    print("start Reveive")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f"rtsp://{login}:{password}@{ip_camera_url}?rtsp_transport=tcp")
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    q.put(frame)
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            q.put(frame)


def Display():
     print("Start Displaying")
     while True: 
        
         if q.empty() !=True:
            frame=q.get()
            cv2.imshow("frame1", frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1=threading.Thread(target=Receive)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=Display)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Когда я запускал этот код на виндовс, всё работало хорошо, так как я использовать 2 отдельных потока для приема и обработки изображения, но когда я перешёл на raspberry pi у меня начались проблеммы. При запуске кода у меня задержка минимум в 5 секунд, а также после 20-25 секунд у меня полность зависает видео, и начинаею лететь ошибки

```
[h264 @ 0xf31deff0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0xf31deff0] error while decoding MB 0 49, bytestream 23091
[h264 @ 0xf310fda0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0xf310fda0] error while decoding MB 0 59, bytestream 1139
[h264 @ 0xf31deff0] error while decoding MB 20 55, bytestream -22
[h264 @ 0xf311d8f0] error while decoding MB 73 51, bytestream -10
[h264 @ 0xf311d8f0] error while decoding MB 119 55, bytestream -9
[h264 @ 0xf31deff0] error while decoding MB 39 5, bytestream -7
[h264 @ 0xf311e8e0] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 0xf311e8e0] error while decoding MB 0 4, bytestream 13479
[h264 @ 0xf310fda0] error while decoding MB 82 11, bytestream -10
[rtsp @ 0xf3100fa0] RTP: PT=69: bad cseq bbbc expected=ac51
```

С сетью проблем нету